# Spring Data JPA: extend a JPA Query generically

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my project I have to implement a multi-tenancy capability (for each customer).
The idea is to store an attribute (customer_id) in every entity for seperation.

To get the data for one customer I need to extend the SQL with this attribute.

Example:

```
billRepository.findByDateAndCustomerId(date, customerId);
```

result is

```
select * from bill where date = ? and customer_id = ?
```

But I want to have a method like

```
billRepository.findByDate(date);
```

and the result shall be the same like above.

```
select * from bill where date = ? and customer_id = ?
```

Is there a possibility to inject the customer_id in a generic way (e.g. sql preprocessor)?
Any idea how to do it with spring-jpa or JPA (hibernate)?

Thanks
chokdee

Comment: Maybe better to mark the other as duplicated, cause this one is older ;-)

Answer (score -2):

I doubt that JPA Api nor Hibernate or any other ORM framework provides such feature. It will be difficult to use. Since customer_id isn't a constant, how could you put the right value? How will you know which queries should change and which not?

Even worse, in my opinion it would be dangeours. Changing the query in a hidden way may allow SQL Injection.

It could be possible override some method from the API to add the new clause that you need but it does not seem a good idea. I think the proper way to create dinamic select queries, changing your code as little as possible, is using the Criteria and the Predicate interfaces.

Comment: Though the poster asks for JPA and this is not JPA, so maybe rewrite what you put using JPA Criteria ?

Comment: Sorry maybe it was misunderstandable. But I mean not to use SQL directly. Using JPA to inject the customer_id in a hidden way.